# How can I initialize or update value of a variable, like with UIKit, in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

How can I initialize or update value of a variable, like with UIKit, in SwiftUI?

For example in the code below I can update my value with action of a `Button` or with `.onAppear()` of `Text`, and there is some other ways. But I am interested if there is a way or tech for coding like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var valueOfA: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        valueOfA = "Magic!" // ← Here(I know it is impossible but if there is a way of this coding?)
        
        Button("change") { valueOfA = "omid" }
        
        Button("nil") { valueOfA = nil }
        
        Text(valueOfA ?? "")
            .onAppear {
                valueOfA = "Some Value"
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What is your *goal*?

Comment: The problem here is that you are changing a `@State` variable in the `body`. This will cause an infinite loop of the view trying to update itself. What do you want instead?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Good Question! Some times we are using GeometryReader for some reason I wanted update my values without using .onAppear or .onChange(), because "value in" is not reachable out side of GeometryReader, and other part of program need those data, I thought if we code just update those like UIKit mode

Comment: It might help if you create an actual example with `GeometryReader` so we can see the big picture here.

Comment: @pawello2222: my Goal is currently to find Answer of Question, what ever if we can find or not, I want be sure about the possibility of initialize or update value of a variable, like with UIKit, in SwiftUI? debugging of this project is not important for me. As you said I wanted give a pic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... it is really like with Alice...

[image: demo]

One has got into mind... probably you wanted this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var valueOfA: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        let valueOfA = self.valueOfA ?? "Magic!"
        
        Button("change") { self.valueOfA = "omid" }
        
        Button("nil") { self.valueOfA = nil }
        
        Text(valueOfA)
            .onAppear {
                self.valueOfA = "Some Value"
            }
    }
}
```

... and by the way we do not change `frame` in `draw(_ rect:)` in UIKit, yes?, but you try to do similar to that.